# URL com letras em caixa-alta

Tags: php, http, url, convenções-de-nome

Existe algum problema em nomear páginas com caixa-alta ?

ex: `http://exemplo.com.br/Minha-Pagina.php`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não. Não há nenhum problema.

Mas você deve pensar sobre o que acontecerá se um usuário tentar acessar `http://exemplo.com.br/minha-pagina.php`  (tudo em minúsculo) ? Página não encontrada ou abrirá a mesma página?

De acordo com o [W3C (Sobre HTML e URLs)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html):

> as URLs geralmente são CASE-SENSITIVE, mas podem haver URLs (ou partes dela) que **não** sejam CASE-SENSITIVE. Os **usuários** devem sempre considerar que as urls são CASE-SENSITIVE.

Porém, sabemos que é mais difícil para o usuário memorizar quais letras são maiúsculas ou minúsculas... é mais simples digitar tudo de uma forma só (maiúsculo ou minúsculo).

Logo, pensando no que o usuário pode digitar, seria interessante deixar que as duas páginas sejam acessíveis, ou seja NÃO CASE-SENSITIVE.

Para não ter nenhum problema com SEO (otimização de buscas), defina qual vai ser o formato padrão da URL, e caso a URL solicitada pelo usuário seja diferente redirecione (com HTTP Status: **301 Moved Permanently**) para a URL no formato padrão.

**UPDATE: Exemplo do redirecionamento em PHP com HTTP Status: 301 Moved Permanently.**

```
$url_padrao = 'http://exemplo.com.br/Minha-Pagina.php';
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: $url_padrao" );
```

Comment: Pode me dar um caminho para me aprofundar nessa parte do redirecionamento ? é no .htacess?

Comment: Coloquei o código do redirecionamento lá na resposta. Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.